# Move files from one directory to another in Azure gen2 using Python

Tags: python-3.x, directory, azure-data-lake

I want to move or copying files after finish the processing from one folder to another inside same container in Azure ADLS gen2.

I am trying to upload files to the new directory but it didn't work with me.

I want a code can copy the files to new directory with same files name.

Comment: what have you tried so far ?
the question needs sufficient code for a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: Could you please provide the error which you are getting?

Answer (score 0):

You can use below code to copy the file from one directory to another directory within the container in ADLS Gen2 using python:

```
 from azure.storage.blob import BlobServiceClient

def copy_files_to_adls(account_url, sas_token, source_container, source_directory, destination_container, destination_directory):
    blob_service_client = BlobServiceClient(account_url=account_url, credential=sas_token) 
    source_container_client = blob_service_client.get_container_client(source_container)
    blobs = source_container_client.list_blobs(name_starts_with=source_directory) 
    for blob in blobs:
        source_blob_path = "<sourcePath>"
        destination_blob_path = "<destinationPat>/<fileName>"
        blob_service_client.get_blob_client(destination_container, destination_blob_path).start_copy_from_url(source_blob_path)    
    print("Files copied successfully!")


account_url = 'https://adlsc.blob.core.windows.net'
account_name = '<accountname>'
account_key = "<accountKey>"
source_container = '<sourceContainer>'
source_directory = '<sourceDirectory>'
destination_container = '<destinationContainer>'
destination_directory = '<destinationDirectory>'

copy_files_to_adls(account_url, account_key, source_container, source_directory, destination_container, destination_directory)
```

[image]

The file is copied successfully.

[image]